# Match URL product landing pages with mixed text and numbers while exluding product variants

Tags: regex

We have a consumer site that I need to look at traffic only to product landing pages and exclude all product variants. I'm really close and can't quite close the loop.

If I have these as sample patters:

products/product-one
products/product-two
products/product-3
products/product-one/30-oz
products/product-one/60-oz
products/product-two/combo-pack
products/product-two/vial-7ml
products/product-3/20-oz

I can exclude all the variants, but I can't figure out how to keep the one product landing page that is products/product-3.

```
products/[\w.*/]((?![1-9]|combo).)*$
```

And do to the fact that we have a ton of media partners, the link could be products/product-3 OR products/product-3/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what strings should be matched and why? `products/(?!product(?=-3(?:/|$))).*` or `products/(?=product-3(?:/|$)).*`?

Comment: *How* do you know it is `products/product-3` you need to keep and not `products/product-two` (or something else)?

Comment: It's based on the link hierarchy. Anything with a pattern products/some-product is a landing page. Anything that has the pattern products/some-product/some-content is the variant. So I know that product-two and product-3 are both product landing pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this regex: `^products\/[^\/]+\/?$`. It will match anything of the form `products/xxx` followed by a trailing `/` or nothing. [Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/p572K8/5).